# Idris type system properties

Tags: coq, dependent-type, idris

Is it theoretically possible to convert any Coq proof to Idris or there are any limitations? More abstract question: Where does Idris type system fall on the lambda cube?

The reason for these questions is that I'm trying to understand how (and if) Idris type system comparable with the Coq type system.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436823/converting-coq-to-idris), but not (currently) answered